initialization of a pointer to a result of a function in C
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int *(*FF(int T[],int k))[2];

int main(){
    int TAB[4][6];
    int *(*(*a_1)(int [], int))[2]=FF+1;
    int *(*a_2)[2]=FF(TAB[1],6)+2;
    int **a_3=*FF(*TAB,0);
    int *a_4=**FF(*TAB,0);
    return 0;
}

Since FF returns a pointer to an array of two pointers to integers, dereferencing the result here *FF(*TAB,0) should be the first pointer in the array of two int pointers, so why is a_3 a double pointer? the same with a_4 - dereferencing a double pointer should return a value (int) but is a pointer.


FF returns a pointer to an array of two pointers to integers

Correct.

dereferencing the result here *FF(*TAB,0) should be the first pointer in the array of two int pointers

This is wrong. The function returns a pointer to an array. Dereferencing gives you the array itself, which then decays to a pointer to its first element. Since the element type is int*, the type decayed from the array is int**.

the same with a_4 - dereferencing a double pointer should return a value (int) but is a pointer

Same as above. Remember that an array decays to a pointer to its first element, not the first element itself.
